# How to set the entry activity of an application on runtime?

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there a way to set the first acitivity of an application on runtime?

I want my application to show different entry activities depending on whether it's the first launch or not. I mean, I could quickly show an activity that decides what's going to be next, but that does not sound like a reasonable approach.

Can you help me?

Comment: Why isn't it a reasonable approach? Genuine curiosity here, I'm just wondering why do you think that.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't a way to do this at runtime. But what you could do is have a lightweight delegate activity that is set as the intent filter for `android.intent.action.MAIN` which will then start another activity based on conditions that you have determined. This activity could be set to have an attribute of `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"` which would make it so that it isn't displayed, but just quickly handles your decisions and disappears. You'll probably also want to set the attribute `android:noHistory="true"` to make sure that the activity is removed from the stack once another activity has been pushed to the top of the stack.

Comment: If you do this in `onStart` of the delegate activity and call `finish` right after `startActivity`, you shouldn't need to set the theme or the no history attributes.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you to use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"` if you're developing for a version greater or equals than 4.0. If you do it without calling `finish()` in `onCreate()`, view will appear showing the old 2.x top frame with the application name. For 4.0 and above use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the onResume method of `AlreadyStartedOnceActivity`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if(prefs.getBoolean("run-once", false))
{
    startActivity(intentToStartOneTimeActivity);
    finish();
}
```

That way, you can leave your "main" activity as the start up activity, but launch the one-time activity from it when you need to.